# "Not in GZIP format" exception while sending data from HttpClient to Jetty embedded

Tags: java, jetty, gzip, httpclient

I'm trying to send data from HttpClient to a server that uses Jetty embedded, hosted on the same machine. The following is the complete stack trace that I get with the error:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:165)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:79)
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:91)
    at wserver.UploadHandler.handle(UploadHandler.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1162)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1096)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-04-05 16:17:47.540:WARN:oejh.HttpParser:qtp1452126962-16: parse exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: too much data seeking EOF in CLOSE for HttpChannelOverHttp@29d04743{r=1,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=null}
```

The error occurs here, on the line instantiating the GZIPInputStream object:

```
ServletInputStream bodyInputStream = request.getInputStream();
GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(bodyInputStream);
```

where `request` is the HttpServletRequest.

This is how I compress my string to gzip:

```
public static byte[] gzip(String content) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try (GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(baos)) {
        gzos.write(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

And this is how I send the using HttpClient:

```
byte[] result = Utils.gzip(pagesJson);

HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://" + serverHost + "/upload");

MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.addBinaryBody("pages", result, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, "pages.bin");
HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
httpPost.addHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_ENCODING, "gzip");
httpPost.setEntity(multipart);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
```

I'm pretty sure I'm messing something up but I'm not sure where exactly. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to send a gzip'd file you do not have to set the header.

```
httpPost.addHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_ENCODING, "gzip");
```

On the server side you also need to take care of multipart requests, for this you can use [Commons FileUpload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/)